# How can I efficiently convert hourly data into dates and times for every day of the year using Python pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas DataFrame that represents a value for every hour of a day and I want to report each value of each day for a year. I have written the 'naive' way to do it. Is there a more efficient way?

Naive way (that works correctly, but takes a lot of time):

```
dfConsoFrigo = pd.read_csv("../assets/datas/refregirateur.csv", sep=';')
dataframe = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Puissance'])
iterator = 0
for day in pd.date_range("01 Jan 2017 00:00", "31 Dec 2017 23:00", freq='1H'):
    iterator = iterator % 24
    dataframe.loc[day] = dfConsoFrigo.iloc[iterator]['Puissance']
    iterator += 1
```

**Input** (time;value) 24 rows:

```
Heure;Puissance
00:00;48.0
01:00;47.0
02:00;46.0
03:00;46.0
04:00;45.0
05:00;46.0
...
19:00;55.0
20:00;53.0
21:00;51.0
22:00;50.0
23:00;49.0
```

**Expected Output** (8760 rows):

```
                     Puissance
2017-01-01 00:00:00         48
2017-01-01 01:00:00         47
2017-01-01 02:00:00         46
2017-01-01 03:00:00         46
2017-01-01 04:00:00         45
...
2017-12-31 20:00:00         53
2017-12-31 21:00:00         51
2017-12-31 22:00:00         50
2017-12-31 23:00:00         49
```

Comment: Can you add some data sample with desired output?

Comment: Is there a date in input or just time?

Comment: in input we have just a time and a value

Comment: How do I know what the date is for those time?   Your output shows multiple dates.

Comment: I have value for time, and i report on any same time for every day in the year, at this moment for exemple :  every 00:00:00 in every day have Value = 48

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [numpy.tile](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html):

```
np.random.seed(10)
df = pd.DataFrame({'Puissance':np.random.randint(100, size=24)})
rng = pd.date_range("01 Jan 2017 00:00", "31 Dec 2017 23:00", freq='1H')

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':np.tile(df['Puissance'].values, 365)}, index=rng)
```

---

```
print (df.head(30))
                      a
2017-01-01 00:00:00   9
2017-01-01 01:00:00  15
2017-01-01 02:00:00  64
2017-01-01 03:00:00  28
2017-01-01 04:00:00  89
2017-01-01 05:00:00  93
2017-01-01 06:00:00  29
2017-01-01 07:00:00   8
2017-01-01 08:00:00  73
2017-01-01 09:00:00   0
2017-01-01 10:00:00  40
2017-01-01 11:00:00  36
2017-01-01 12:00:00  16
2017-01-01 13:00:00  11
2017-01-01 14:00:00  54
2017-01-01 15:00:00  88
2017-01-01 16:00:00  62
2017-01-01 17:00:00  33
2017-01-01 18:00:00  72
2017-01-01 19:00:00  78
2017-01-01 20:00:00  49
2017-01-01 21:00:00  51
2017-01-01 22:00:00  54
2017-01-01 23:00:00  77
2017-01-02 00:00:00   9
2017-01-02 01:00:00  15
2017-01-02 02:00:00  64
2017-01-02 03:00:00  28
2017-01-02 04:00:00  89
2017-01-02 05:00:00  93
```

Comment: At this time my code works, but is very slow, thats my problem.

Define index before assign instead of use .loc is faster ?

Comment: Sure, but need align data. So if data are repeating every hour, then it sholud works nice.

Comment: hum i need to precise the question, my input is a 24 row dataframe, that i want to repeat on every day of a year. in fact i just want repeat my dataframe 364 times.

Comment: Yes, now understand. Give me some time